# Trying to understand getThreads in GAS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail

I am new to app script and I am trying to read an email from my inbox. I thought that getThreads would do the job but I still don't fully understand how to use it. When I try to execute the code I wrote below it comes up with a null error.

Looking at the [documentation of `getThreads()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-label#getThreads()), they use the example:

```
 // Log the subject lines of the threads labeled with MyLabel
 var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("MyLabel");
 var threads = label.getThreads();
 for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
   Logger.log(threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject());
 }
```

what does "MyLabel" stand for?

This is the code i tried that failed

```
function myFunction() {


   var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('bobtheman@gmail.com');
   var threads = label.getThreads();


     for (var t in threads) {
       var thread = threads[t];

    // Gets the message body
       var message = thread.getMessages()[0].getPlainBody();
     }

  GmailApp.sendEmail('barbrabat@gmail.com', 'hola', message)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

MyLabel is the label of the email. It depends whether you added a label to a specific email or not. You can use the search method instead.

```
function myFunction(){
   var label = 'yourLabel'; // if no label, remove the label in search
   // it would be better if you add a label to a specific email for fast and more precise searching
   var searchEmail = GmailApp.search('from:me subject:"' + subject + '" label:' + label + '');
   var threadId = searchEmail[0].getId(); // get the id of the search email
   var thread = GmailApp.getThreadById(threadId); // get email thread using the threadId
   var emailMsg = thread.getMessages()[0]; // get the content of the email
   var emailContent = emailMsg.getPlainBody(); // get the body of the email
   // check using log
   Logger.log(emailContent);
   // how to open log
   // Ctrl + Enter
   // Run this function before checking the log
}
```

Thanks